# Is it possible to convert a struct to a map in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

Suppose I have a struct:

```
myStruct = struct()
myStruct.a = 1;
myStruct.b = 20;
myStruct.c = 4;
```

Is it possible to convert it to map where the keys are the struct fields? For example, `myMap('a')` should return `1`.

Comment: While @Luis's answer is correct, I'd note that you can get map-like behavior from structs using dynamic field names: `myStruct.('a') == 1`.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Good point. Probably the map can be avoided altogether

Comment: I was not aware of the dynamic field names. This, as well as Luis' answer, solves my problem.

Comment: I'm curious about performance? IMHO lack of a Hashmap solution at all comparable to STL hash_map is a big shortcoming of Matlab environment :/  There are hack type things you can do, but nothing both clean and effective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done as follows:

```
myMap = containers.Map(fieldnames(myStruct), struct2cell(myStruct));
```

This uses the syntax `myMap = containers.Map(keys, values)`, where

- `keys` is a cell array of the field names of `myStruct`, generated by the function [`fieldnames`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html);
- `values`is a cell array of the values of `mystruct`, obtained with [`struct2cell`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html).